# No operations defined in spec Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, documentation

**swagger ui**

[image]
i'm trying to solve this problem but somehow i still didn't manage to do it. /swagger endpoint seems to read only part of the swagger.json file. I configured everything and still not a single error popped up. It just says  "No operations defined in spec" even tho i created one test model. Googling this was a disaster,so few articles and they are all different completely.

**in app.js i added :**

```
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import * as swaggerDoc from "./swagger.json";
app.use("/swagger", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc));
```

**in swagger.json :**

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Stefan Back-end Swagger",
    "description": "Test",
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "Cat": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "genus": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Cat should be under "definitions" in a swagger file to be later referenced in a "path" definition. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/

Comment: @volcanic where do i need to put the path ? and yes,for definitions,it was my mistake. Nothing,found it,gonna try. Thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

You are using openapi-3, look at the [components section](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/),

Your `swagger.json` file should be like:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Stefan Back-end Swagger",
    "description": "Test",
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schema": {
      "Cat": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "genus": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this help.